# Removing '-' on linux md5sum

Tags: linux, shell

When I try to encode the password variable into md5sum, it is giving me a string with the md5sum encoding **and** a dash at the end. And when I try to put a dash after it, it doesn't work. So my questions is:
How can I remove the dash on the md5sum output of the linux terminal? Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Password: ' passwordInput
Password=$(echo -n "$passwordInput" | md5sum)
if [ $Password = "0cbc6611f5540bd0809a388dc95a615b" ]; then
    clear
    echo "Password is good"
else
    clear
    echo "Password is bad"
fi
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

read Test
Password=$(echo -n "$Test" | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
echo ""
if [ $Password = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" ]; then
      clear
      echo "WhOop WHOop"
else
      echo ":("
fi
```

Comment: You could use BASH pattern substitution instead of `cut` as in `if [ ${Password/ -} = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" ];`

Comment: If you don't like `cut` then you can also use `awk`: `echo "$Test" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' `

Answer (score 5):

You have three problems.

First, your question is not very clear. Please update it to state clearly just what you're asking (how you want your program to behave, and how it fails to do so). In this case it's not too hard to figure out from your code, but that's not always true. You write

> I don't get the "-" out of the linux md5sum.

but in fact the problem is that you *are* getting the "-" (and probably more as well).

(UPDATE: Better now, thanks.)

Second, the output of the `md5sum` includes some extra information after the displayed checksum, and you need to remove it. (It would be nice if `md5sum` had an option to print *just* the checksum, but it doesn't.) Fortunately, it's easy to strip the extra information; it's just a space character and everything following it.

Third, because you're using single quotes:

```
Password="$(echo -n '$Test' | md5sum)"
```

the string you're passing to `md5sum` is literally `'$Test'`, not the value of your variable.

Fixing the second and third problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

read Test
Password="$(echo -n "$Test" | md5sum | sed 's/ .*$//')"
echo ""
if [ "$Password" = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" ]; then
    clear
    echo "WhOop WHOop"
else
    echo ":("
fi
```

I'd normally criticize your use of the `clear` command, but in this case you're erasing a password that the user entered. But you're not clearing the screen if the user enters an incorrect password. Bash's `read` command has an option to suppress echoing of input, and this is the perfect use for it.  Here's how I might do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Password: " -s Test
Password="$(echo -n "$Test" | md5sum | sed 's/ .*$//')"
echo ""
if [ "$Password" = "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" ]; then
    echo "WhOop WHOop"
else
    echo ":("
fi
```

(Incidentally, the empty string is a lousy password, as is anything whose md5sum can be found with a quick Google search -- like "`Test`".)

Answer (score 1):

The "-" in the md5sum indicates, that you are using standard input for md5sum. If you would be using md5sum for a file, a filename would be displayed in that place.

Comment: Without the dash: printf '%s' 'some string' | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from @user1918305's suggestion, `md5` will operate on a string input.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

$ printf "hello world" | md5sum
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3  -
$ printf "hello world" | md5sum | grep -o '^\S\+'
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3
$ printf "hello world" | md5
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3
```

Comment: This is the answer